# Are justifications of finalized block canonical?

Tags: consensus, finality, justification

Justifications are external to the signed part of the Substrate block, meaning they change after block is produced initially.

However, I'm wondering if there is any assumption in Substrate (or otherwise, let's say in specific consensus engine) that they are canonical after block is finalized or can they still change even after that?

[This test case](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/48d4313151873e3ce8be877efb9e485649264f5e/client/api/src/in_mem.rs#L860-L872) seems to imply it is not the case, but maybe it is just a test case.